# JSON string parsing for ordered pairs in ruby

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

Here is my JSON

```
  "status": "ok",
  "name": "blah",
  "unit": "blahblah",
  "period": "bluh",
  "description": "Average blah across major blahs.",
  "values": [
    {
      "x": 1459382400,
      "y": 416.94
    },
    {
      "x": 1459468800,
      "y": 416.25
    },
```

I am wondering if there is a way to subtract each 'y' by the subsequent 'y' value into a independent variable.

```
Simplified expression of code
conn = Net::HTTP.get URI('http://www.blah.blahblah/bluhblahbleh')
parsed = JSON.parse(conn)
puts parsed ["values"]  # this prints all ordered pairs child to "values"
#This wouldn't work for me
puts parsed["values"]["y"]
#no luck here either
puts parsed["values", "y"]
```

Should I utilize `.each do |line|` approach? # Line by Line?

Any guidance, wisdom or meaningless conversation is valued.

Comment: `parsed["values"].map { |e| e["y"] }.reduce(:-)`

Comment: You guys/gals are great human beings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works for what you want to do

```
require 'json'

json = '{"status": "ok", "name": "blah", "unit": "blahblah", "period": "bluh", "description": "Average blah across major blahs.", "values": [ { "x": 1459382400, "y": 416.94 }, { "x": 1459468800, "y": 416.25 }, { "x": 1459468800, "y": 417.25 }]}'
data = JSON.parse(json)

values_with_change = [data['values'][0]]

data['values'].each_cons(2) do |value|
  change = value[1]['y'] - value[0]['y']
  value_with_change = value[1].merge({change: change})
  values_with_change.push(value_with_change)
end

values_with_change
```

Outputs

```
 => [{"x"=>1459382400, "y"=>416.94, :change=>0.0}, {"x"=>1459468800, "y"=>416.25, :change=>-0.6899999999999977}, {"x"=>1459468800, "y"=>417.25, :change=>1.0}]
```

Comment: Use [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), don’t invent a wheel.

Comment: `data['values'].each_cons(2) do |(v1, v2)| ...`

Comment: How would I find the sum of all :change